# Components Supported by the DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing

I want to know the components that are supported by the DefaultTableCellRenderer other than JCheckbox and JComboBox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if you want to insert some components (e.g. `JTextField`) in a `JTable` cells, you can create a custom renderer like:

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
//.....
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
   //create a component according to arguments recieved, and return
   //e.g. in simplest terms
   return new JTextField();
  }
```

then you can use that renderer in your table using `setDefaultRenderer()` method for each column

Comment: Thnks vishal..for the same i want to add button instead of textfield, hw can i get it.

Comment: did you try creating `JButton` in that method according to your requirement and return it?

Answer (score 2):

`DefaultTableCellRenderer` itself does not render a checkbox or a combobox. It is `JTable` that providers some defaults renderers that are used based on `getColumnClass()` implementation. Here is the code from `JTable` that initializes some default renderers that are implemented as inner classes:

```
protected void createDefaultRenderers() {
    defaultRenderersByColumnClass = new UIDefaults(8, 0.75f);

    // Objects
    setLazyRenderer(Object.class,
            "javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer$UIResource");

    // Numbers
    setLazyRenderer(Number.class, "javax.swing.JTable$NumberRenderer");

    // Doubles and Floats
    setLazyRenderer(Float.class, "javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer");
    setLazyRenderer(Double.class, "javax.swing.JTable$DoubleRenderer");

    // Dates
    setLazyRenderer(Date.class, "javax.swing.JTable$DateRenderer");

    // Icons and ImageIcons
    setLazyRenderer(Icon.class, "javax.swing.JTable$IconRenderer");
    setLazyRenderer(ImageIcon.class, "javax.swing.JTable$IconRenderer");

    // Booleans
    setLazyRenderer(Boolean.class, "javax.swing.JTable$BooleanRenderer");
}
```

The initialized `defaultRenderersByColumnClass` hashtable is then used in `getDefaultRenderer()`.

Comment: Using DefaultTableCellRenderer, JTextField can be inserted to the JTable cells?

Comment: @deva Not sure I understand the question. Are you referring to renderer or editor?

Comment: @deva `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends `JLabel`.  You would have to create your own renderer.